# Alert box that plays sound when is shown

Tags: javascript

I want to add an alert box with dialog and when it's shown an audio file is played,

here is what I have now:

```
    <audio autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">
    <source src="Funk.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
alert("alert box");
</script>
```

but the problem is that when the page loads it shows the alert, and then, when I click ok it plays the sound file.

what I would like is to have the sound playing when the alert box is shown.

thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried playing the audio using js before opening the alert? `document.getElementById("yourAudioId").play();` then `alert();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in a setTimeout callback should work, probably even without the delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("alert box");
}, 0);
```

Alerts generally don't like other things launched together with them, so this little trick should do. You can also play the file using JS, but I believe you'd still need a tiny delay for the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `autoplay` functionality, and add this to your `script`:

```
var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

audio.play();
alert('Now playing ...');
audio.pause();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhg17qs5/)

(Turn down your volume before opening the Fiddle!)

Also note that you don't need to include `language` and `type` in the script tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
```

Simply do this:

```
<script>
```

Comment: this is what I have now, but still don't play, now not even after clicking ok:


`<audio>
  <source src="Funk.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<script>
var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

audio.play();
alert("\alert");
audio.pause();`

Comment: Hmm, you may need to put this in a timeout like @Shomz suggested, and possibly use a delay to ensure the audio file has time to load.